# ASP.NET Core: Feed Server Timing Headers from OpenTelemetry

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, open-telemetry, server-timing

I'd like to make use of the Server Timing API (which is a set of HTTP headers) to inform the client (browser) which operations are performed on the backend and their timings.
My app (ASP.NET Core 6) is already instrumented with OpenTelemetry. It already collects metrics from database requests as well as our own application operations.

What I would like is to create a middleware in the end of the pipeline which can introspect the already collected metrics/traces and create appropriate headers for response.

But I can't figure out how to get access to the collected metrics. Should I create an Exporter or something else?